# Does MTK Android devices get software updates ever? (LG)

Tags: updates, lg, rom-update

I know that mediatek doesn't share their source code (you can buy it), and what I was wondering is does any MTK device gets updates when newer Android version rolls out, and not just new versions, just does they get software updates? I asking about stock ROM-s made by phone manufacturer. Mostly interested about LG devices.

Comment: It may help to read this post on how updates make it to devices. Remember if the device manufacturer doesn't do the work - its up to any community around that device to create updated ROMs.: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65557/is-there-a-technical-reason-android-update-story-is-so-bad

Comment: @Morrison Chang well this is different you can't make ROM without sources which in case of mediatek will never be published, and mostly their politics where devices don't get updates for example from KK to LP instead of that you have to buy new device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - devices from Xiaomi are good examples.

[Redmi Note 2](http://www.miui.com/download-290.html), released in 2015, still gets stable and weekly development builds of up-to-date MIUI8. Whether the Android version beneath the UI was updated is a question, but that also stays true for other MIUI devices regardless of the SoCs they're using, and you're not asking about Android version updates exactly, either.

Comment: Hm, thanks, well when I said that I don't mean on updating android versions I meant on not updating from kit - kat to lollipop bu bug fixes and security updates and such things, which are actually android updates but not strictly just that (well I'm interested in any kind of updates that MTK devices get). I didn't explain well. In case of Xiaomi I think there is just MIUI updates.

Comment: Xiaomi did give those devices monthly security patches, though mostly in development builds and usually a bit delayed. Anyway, the point is MTK devices do get major and minor updates, but that heavily depends on the manufacturer you're looking at.

Comment: Do you know anything about LG an their deliver of updates to mtk devices? I don't know when they started to use their chip, it is in K series, maybe in Lxx series.

Comment: L Bello (MT6582) did not get a single update as far as my search returned. Other even lower-end L devices presumably suffered the same fate. As for K/X series, they started very recently so not much can be said. I assume you want to buy one of those in the future? Well my suggestion is... just don't.

Comment: Well I allredy boght one K8 actually, about two months ago. Didn't know anything about mediatek and how things work. It's sad because fon could run Nougat, but probably never get it. And making/porting a custom rom is pain in the ass for mtk devices, it's hard for every phone but this is new level of hard. I think that K10 was LP than get MM but I'm not sure.