# Why don't new android versions work out-of-the box on non-Google phones?

Tags: custom-roms

You can install desktop OS's on basically any device...

Why don't new android versions work unless customizations are made for the specific device model?

Comment: One reason is that Android phones are embedded devices and thus not standardized on lower level. On a PC you have UEFI which provides a standardized API you can rely when starting an OS. Embedded devices have their bootloader which is CPU/chipset specific and thus Android have to be adapted for every device.

Comment: See: [Is there a technical reason Android update story is so bad?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65557/3573)

Comment: Further see: [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) // [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575) // [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/16575) …