# How do phones from non-famous brands usually update their version of Android?

Tags: updates

Stuff like [11T Pro](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003594960752.html) or [i13 Pro Max](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003988195506.html) are just examples of Android phones that don't have any famous brand.  My question is, how do these phones usually allow us to update?

Is the updating mechanism something in Android itself and is done from Google's servers?  Similar to how Microsoft Windows updates itself regardless of which PC hardware we use?

Comment: These type of phones are largely considered disposable and are not updated, ever... Not the OS anyways, apps would be updated via your software store of choice (Google Play, F-Droid, etc).

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Is there a technical reason Android update story is so bad?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65557/44325) (posted in 2014, but still relevant until now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to a PC the update process is a bit different, because Google does not provide binary updates for devices (only modern devices load some system apps via Google Play Store but these system apps only cover a small part of the OS).

Google Android devices always load their updates from a site operated by the phone manufacturer. Google is in the update process only involved at two points:

1. Google provides the security and/feature updates in source code form, which are then compiled and integrated by the phone manufacturer into their device fimware.
2. After everything is ready for an update Google gets the update an proves if it is compliant to a large list for rules each device and firmware have to satisfy. If the update passes all test the manufacturer gets the OK from Google and can then provide the update on their servers.

How long, how often or if a device gets updates at all depends on the phone manufacturer. The general rule is that the cheaper the phone the less updates you will get. For the extra cheap section on AliExpress or similar sites this means you are lucky if you get an update at all.